# Permission to Hide Workflow button and stop user to edit another users items.

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, ootb

In SharePoint online i have a Custom list with name **Company** , Inside that I have view  called **All Items**. 
in that view user can **add new item** , and **edit the item**. 
I have workflow attached to the list. I am trying to **hide Workflow button** for **User**    [image]

So Is that possible using OOTB permission ? 
i want to show that workflow button for Admin Group not for user ..

also I am trying to add some permission so user can not edit the item created by another user..

please share your thoughts..
all this i want to do using ootb ..

Answer (score 0):

For 1st question, you can open your site with SharePoint Designer > Lists and Libraries > **Company**. In **Custom Action** click **create**. Then create an action maybe call "start workflow" and in **type of action** choose initiate a workflow. In the Rights Mask field you may insert "ManageWeb" so that only user with "Manage web" permission can see the action button.

Then you need to hide the OOTB "Workflows" button. Sorry I am not sure how to do. Maybe you can hide it with CSS?

For 2nd question, you can create a workflow that will be auto started when new item is added. The workflow will change the permission of that item so that only the admin and item creator have right to edit. All other users have read only.

[Setup custom action reference](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/sharepoint-designer-custom-actions)

[Mask reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx)