# Remove "Workflows" from Advanced

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to hide "Workflows" from the Advanced options when clicking (...) next to an item in SharePoint Online? Preferably using Security Trimmed Controls, but a script editor would work too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has already been answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179559/permission-to-hide-workflow-button-and-stop-user-to-edit-another-users-items/179567).

There doesn't seem to be an OOTB feature to do that. What you can do is to get the ID or CSS class of that option and then do with CSS:

```
<style type= text/css>
    #id { display:none }
</style>
```

Or with JS:

```
$("#id").hide();
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the ID or CSS class?

Comment: Use the Chrome DevTools (Gogle Chrome) or Page Inspector (Firefox) and locate the code associated to "Workflow" option

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a#ID_Workflows.ms-contextmenu-link { display:none; }
    a#ID_CA_Compliance Details.ms-contextmenu-link { display:none; }
    a#ID_CA_Follow.ms-contextmenu-link { display:none; }
    a#ID_Subscribe.ms-contextmenu-link { display:none; }
</style>
```

I couldn't get:

```
a#ID_CA_Compliance Details.ms-contextmenu-link { display:none; }
```

Due to the space between Compliance and Details. Quotes don't work, how can I group the ID name together?